# How can I change a css property after it has been @keyframe animated?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I'm fading in some buttons with @keyframe animation from opacity: 0 to opacity: 1.

```
div{
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fadeIn 1s forwards;    
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
    }100%{
        opacity: 1;   
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
    }100%{
        opacity: 1;   
    }
}

div:hover{
    opacity: .5 !important; /* THIS DOES NOT HAPPEN BECAUSE THE OPACITY WAS ANIMATED */
    color: red;
}
```

On :hover, I'd like to change the opacity to .5 but it appears that after a property is animated using @keyframe, it can't be changed.

Simple example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lzcedmuq/3/

---

PS: In the real web-app, I am also scaling the buttons in so the fix I need is more than just for opacity. I need to be able to change any property that has been animated. I can do it with JS hackery but I don't want to.

Comment: You should tell us about browsers you have tested this on

Comment: Tested on Chrome 42 and Safari OSX. Confirmed it does work on FF.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Disable the animation as part of the hover state:

```
div:hover{
    opacity: .5;
    -webkit-animation: none;
    animation: none;
    color: red;
}
```

One issue with this is that the animation will restart when the hover ends.

Comment: Nice trick... but how to stop the animation to run again after the element is not being hovered anymore? Every time I move the cursor outside my element, the original animation, that is already finished, runs again...

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the problem

```
opacity: 0.5 !important;
```

I can't answer to why the browser doesn't allow changes to animated styles, but it must have a higher priority then any new specified styles... so with that in mind you can use the !important to force that style to take top priority.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/floor_/6Loy22Lc/)

Comment: Didn't work for me in Chrome 42. What browser? I'm updating the jsfiddle link to include that though because it feels like it SHOULD work.

Comment: hmm so it doesn't work in chrome, I am testing other browsers now and I will get back to you