# Is this a proper use case for the CSS !important rule?

Tags: html, css

I am aware that `!important` is not recommended, and the few known use cases where it is appropriate includes when working with third party libraries such as Bootstrap. However, i would like to ask if this use case is appropriate too. Suppose i have a `<div/>` which i would want to animate from background-color transparent to a certain color. However, i would like to have a color change on hover too after the animation happens, but i can't seem to find a way to do it without using the `!important` rule. Thanks in advance!

```
div{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: animate 4s forwards;
}

div:hover{
  background-color: blue !important;
}


@keyframes animate{
  from {
    background-color: transparent;   
  }

  to {
    background-color: maroon;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can add `animation: none;` to your hover rule but it will have the unwanted effect of restarting the animation.. not sure if there's a way around that.  using `!important` might be your best option. more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705327/how-can-i-change-a-css-property-after-it-has-been-keyframe-animated)

Comment: also, @Jarrett - I find nothing wrong with your question but asking if something is "appropriate" here tends to draw close votes since there's concern that many answers are going to be opinion based.  instead you might ask "how can I get this done without using `!important`"

Comment: @Alohci oh ok nice thanks for your reply!

Comment: @billynoah Thanks for your reply! Would structure my questions better in the future.

Comment: now your question is a complete new one since the update, you may want to notice the other user so they can update their answers too

Comment: Oh ok sure, but how can i do that?

Comment: Modifying a question in a way it invalidates already posted answers is frawned upon. The best here is to post a new question specifically about color since this rule is different than background-color

Comment: Oh ok sure thanks so much for the advice! Will note that for the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not judging if it would be an appropriate use of `!important` here or not, one way around in your case would be to split your animation and transition on two different elements. Note that it's quite common to do so when you want to animate and transition the same properties.

`background-color` even has the advantage that you can use pseudo-elements instead of a plain one.

Less talk, more code:

```css
div{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: animate 4s forwards;
}
div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: background-color 2s;
}
div:hover::after{
  background-color: blue;
}

@keyframes animate{
  from {
    background-color: transparent;   
  }
  to {
    background-color: maroon;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: When you say that `background-color` has the advantage that you can use pseudo-elements instead of a plain one, does it mean to use the `::after` property? However, does it not work with `color`?

Comment: Yes it's what it means and no, that won't work with `color`.

Comment: Oh that's unfortunate, because i wanted to work with `color` too. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The OP changed the question completely

Comment: @TemaniAfif just waking up and I have nor the head nor the time to read the diff. But if this edit invalidates previous answers what prevents you from rolling it back?

Answer (score 1):

What I prefer to do is unsetting the property beforehand I want to customise with the bootstrap, say I want to change button's default blue colour to red, I do it using,

```
background-color: unset;
background-color: #ff000;
```

Keep in mind, the order of code matters here by a lot

Answer (score 1):

Do the animation differently and don't rely on forwards

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: animate 4s;
  background-color: maroon;
  transition: background-color 2s;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Won't work *during* the animation, but probably good enough for OP

Comment: @Kaiido it does work during the animation (at least on Chrome) but without the transition. Not sure if the transition is needed or not based on the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however i was planning to do the animations for `color` for a few elements, and i will have a `animation-delay` property on some of them. And i would put a `color: transparent` on the elements before their animation happens. Sorry for confusing by giving an example of `background-color` anyway.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes it does work without the transition too.

Comment: @Jarrett you can always update your question to show a more relevant example close to your real use case in order to get more accurate answers

Comment: @Jarrett based on your edit, if you replaced background-color with color in my answer it will also work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226470/discussion-between-jarrett-and-temani-afif).